# socket.io traffic for other rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Why do i see traffic for other rooms in (chrome/network).

Node.js and socket.io 0.9.16

Simplified setup

```
//sockets-server
socket.on('subscribeToSome', function (data) {
    joinToRoom(socket, data);
    console.log("joining" + data.room);
 });

 //client
 socket.emit(subscribeToSome, {room: room, data: dataToSubscribe});
   socket.on(room, function(data){
   console.log(data);
 });


//route -server
global.io.sockets.emit("room1", {aa:"ads"}
```

Everything works but i can see traffic for other rooms in (chrome/network) even doe in not member of it. (data is not visible in the callback only in network/Websockets)

How come? And how do i solve it.

Thanks. //Karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can see from your code you're not emitting your message to a room but you use an eventname for the message. As shown in the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-%E2%80%A6]):socket), `emit` takes a String as the first parameter, giving that message a name which your callbacks are hooked to.

Emitting to a room would look like the following:

```
global.io.sockets.to("room1").emit("message", {aa:"ads"}
```

You also need to join your socket into that room for it to receive the respective messages.

See http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ for more information on that topic.

Comment: ah, ok is it possible to create a dynamic event listener. (like an callback as in above).

Comment: hmm, seems like i just could use. to("room1").emit("room1", {aa:"ads"});